# How does the Safari Javascript console predict properties of nonexistent objects?

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-web-inspector

Please note, I have not been able to reproduce this behavior in Chrome or Firefox, just Safari.

Let’s say I have a function with two possible randomly-selected return values: `{ foo: 'test' }` and `{ bar: 'test' }`.

```
function getObj() {
    console.log('This code has been executed.');
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        return { foo: 'test' };
    } else {
        return { bar: 'test' };
    }
}
```

When I type an invocation of the function **but do not press “enter”**, Safari’s predictions can still make assumptions about the return value. Sometimes it sees one return value, sometimes it sees the other.

Sometimes one:

￼[image]

Sometimes the other:

[image]

Obviously, by simply typing the function invocation, I’m not calling the function *as I understand it*, and I do not see a console.log saying “This code has been executed.” How does Safari do this?

Comment: Safari or chrome does [evaluate the function](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/expressions), but they do so on another layer without modifying internal values.

Comment: Helpful link. Thanks!

Comment: @Ibu Actually, that link doesn't really explain the separate layer you're speaking of. Also, Chrome doesn't actually do this, from what I have seen. Just Safari.